# How can I print words till reached specific word?

Tags: python

file1 = ...blahblahblah\nblah Lawyer Amy\nblahblah.... : want to print "Lawyer Amy"

file2 = ...\nblahblahblahblah Lawyer Amy(goverment)\nblahblah.... : want to print "Lawyer Amy(goverment)"

file3 = ...blah\nblahblahblah Lawyer Amy, Michael, Messi\nblahblah.... : want to print "Lawyer Amy, Michael, Messi"

so I need to print "Lawyer ~ before\n"

How can I solve this problem?

```
pseudo code:
f = open(file)
readline = f.readLine()
lawyer = re.findall("Laywer", readline)
print from lawyer till "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex find all approach:

```py
file2 = "\nblahblahblahblah Lawyer Amy(goverment)\nblahblah"
output = re.findall(r'\bLawyer[^\n]+', file2)
print(output)  # ['Lawyer Amy(goverment)']
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  My answer is already cutting off all text from the first `\n` after `Lawyer` onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does what you want. It opens the file and start printing its lines. When a given keyword is contained in a line, it breaks the loop.

```
def print_until(file, keyword):
    with open(file, 'r') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            print(line)
            if keyword in line:
                break
```